# Angular 4 Dynamically add a click event

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I need to dynamically add a click event to an div tag:

```
<div *ngIf="item.click">
    <div (click)="item.click" >{{item.name}} (should trigger( {{item.click}})</div>
</div>
```

My object looks like this:

```
item: {name: 'Action', click: '_actionService.triggerAction()'}
```

I don't get any error when running the code but the click event doesn't seem to have been created.

Any suggestions?

Comment: i am not quite sure if this is possible will be glad if i am wrong

Comment: There is no way to add click handlers dynamically using Angular bindings. Rather do something like `(click)="item.click ? doSomething($event) : null"` to only call `doSomething()` in case of a user click when `item.click` is truthy.

Comment: I'm not sure what `(click)="item.click"` is supposed to do (it won't do anything how it is currently)

Comment: It's supposed to trigger the function _actionService.triggerAction()

Comment: This is not how it works, why not defining real function on `item` elements instead of strings ?

Comment: I need this because the actions will be dynamic. This is possible with pure typescript, but I would like to do this in the template if possible

Comment: something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42966681/adding-a-click-event-to-a-dynamically-created-html-element-using-angular2 ? or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35080387/dynamically-add-event-listener-in-angular-2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not see any problem in adding a dynamic click. However, your item should be something like:

```
item: {name: 'Action', click: '_actionService.triggerAction'}
```

So, the click property in the item is the function not the result. *_actionService.triggerAction()* >>> *_actionService.triggerAction*

And then the htmlshould be something like :

```
<div (click)="item.click.call()" >
```

Hope that is helpful!

That is the actual code I have tryed:

Component:

```
 ... implements OnInit {

  public item: any = { name: 'name', click: () => { console.log('Some clcik has happened') } }

...
```

html :

```
<div (click)="item.click.call()"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but this doesn't work. I get a error: "v.parent.context.$implicit.click.call is not a function"

Comment: Is  **_actionService.triggerAction**  a function ? In that case can you post more code so we can check where is the problem

Comment: Thanks man! With your edit I was able to get this to work using " item: {name: 'Action', click: () => {this._actionService.triggerAction()} )"